# How to prove $(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^3_{i})^{1/3}\cdot (1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^3_{i})^{1/3}\ge 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}-b_{i}|$?

Tags: inequality

> let $a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n},b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n}$ be postive numbers, and such
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}\le 1,\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^2_{i}\le 1$$
>   show that
>   $$\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^3_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot
> \left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^3_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\ge 
> 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}-b_{i}|$$

My idea:
since $$a_{i},b_{i}\in (0,1]\Longrightarrow |a_{i}-b_{i}|\le 1\Longrightarrow |a_{i}-b_{i}|\ge |a_{i}-b_{i}|^2=a^2_{i}+b^2_{i}-2a_{i}b_{i}$$

so
$$RHS\le 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}-b_{i}|^2=1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^2_{i}$$
so we only prove
$$\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^3_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^3_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^3_{i}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^3_{i}\right)^{1/3}\ge 1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^2_{i}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^3_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^3_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^3_{i}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^3_{i}\ge \left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^2_{i}\right)^3$$

I think this maybe can use Holder inequality to solve it. And I found this inequality is stronger Holder inequality. Thank you

Comment: Why is it true when $(a_i)=(0,0,\ldots,0)$?

Answer (score 3):

The best result I could get :

> $\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^3_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot
> \left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^3_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\ge 
> 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}-b_{i}| - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{2 a_{i}b_{i}}$

The method I used in trying to prove the claim:

Let's take $0\leq x\leq1 $ we have $0\leq 1-x\leq1 $ and : $$(1-x)+x \leq 1 $$

If we take the both parts to powers $ m \geq 1 $ they can only get smaller so :
$$ \forall\ m \geq 1 , (1-x)^{m}+x^{m} \leq 1 $$

$$ \forall\ m \geq 1 , (1-x)^{m} \leq 1 - x^{m}$$

lets put $x = \sum x_{i}$ where $x_{i}$ are positive numbers :

$$ \forall\ m \geq 1 ,(1-\sum x_{i})^{m} \leq 1 - (\sum x_{i})^{m} \leq 1 - \sum x_{i}^{m}$$

> We have then our lemma :
>
> $$ \sum x_{i} \leq 1 \Rightarrow  \forall\ m \geq 1 , \big(1 - \sum x_{i}^{m}\big)  \geq \big(1-\sum x_{i}\big)^m $$
>   and if $ \big(1 - \sum x_{i}^{m}\big) \ge 0 $ and $\big(1 - \sum x_{i}\big) \leq 0 $ we still have :
>   $$ \forall\ m \geq 1 , \big(1 - \sum x_{i}^{m}\big)^{1/m}  \geq \big(1-\sum x_{i}\big)$$

Back to our problem :
 $$ L = \left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^3_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot
\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^3_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} = \left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a^{2}_{i})^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot
\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} (b^{2}_{i})^{\frac{3}{2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$ \ge \left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot
\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n} b^{2}_{i} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

(We got here by lemma for $m = 3/2$ and $x_i = a_i^2$)

$$ \ge \left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i} + \sum_{i \not=j}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{j}-\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} -\sum_{i=1}^{n} b^{2}_{i} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

$$  = \left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i} + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i} + \sum_{i \not=j}^{n} a^{2}_{i}b^{2}_{j} -\sum_{i=1}^{n} ( a^{2}_{i} + b^{2}_{i} ) \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

$$  = \left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i}  -\sum_{i=1}^{n} ( a^{2}_{i} + b^{2}_{i} -2a_{i}b_{i}) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i} + \sum_{i \not=j}^{n} a^{2}_{i}b^{2}_{j} - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

I blocked here, I **WAS NOT ABLE** to prove that (Wich is false by the way see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840839/proof-or-disproof-y-2-sum-i-1n-a2-i-b2-i-sum-i-not-jn?lq=1)) :

$$ 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i} + \sum_{i \not=j}^{n} a^{2}_{i}b^{2}_{j} - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i} \geq 0 $$

But we can easily prove that (using the lemma):

$$  L \ge 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i} -\sum_{i=1}^{n} ( a^{2}_{i} + b^{2}_{i} - 2 a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i})^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

OR :

> $$  L \ge 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i} -\sum_{i=1}^{n} | a_{i} + b_{i}|  $$

Or

> $\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^3_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\cdot
> \left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^3_{i}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}\ge 
> 1-\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}b_{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i}-b_{i}| - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{2 a_{i}b_{i}}$

Edit : Here is my attempt to fix it :

$$ L \geq \left(1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i}  -\sum_{i=1}^{n} ( a^{2}_{i} + b^{2}_{i} -2a_{i}b_{i}) + 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i} + \sum_{i \not=j}^{n} a^{2}_{i}b^{2}_{j} - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

Let's put :
$$ X = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i}  -\sum_{i=1}^{n} ( a^{2}_{i} + b^{2}_{i} -2a_{i}b_{i}) $$

$$ R = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i}  -\sum_{i=1}^{n} | a_{i} - b_{i} | $$
and

$$ Y = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i} + \sum_{i \not=j}^{n} a^{2}_{i}b^{2}_{j} - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i} $$

- if $R < 0 $ the originale inequality holds : **OK**

if $0 \leq R \leq 1 $ then $0 \leq X \leq 1 $ and we have $ 0 \leq X + Y \leq 1 $ so $ -1 \leq Y \leq 1 $

- if $Y > 0$: **OK**

$(X+Y)^{1/2} \ge \sqrt {X} $ then by the lemma we have the wanted inequality.

- if $Y < 0 $ : **NOT OK**

$(X+Y)^{1/2} = (\sqrt X ^2-\sqrt{-Y}^2)^{1/2} = ((\sqrt X -\sqrt{-Y})(\sqrt X +\sqrt{-Y}))^{1/2} \ge  ? $

.. then .. ?? :(

Comment: Hello,$a_{i}>0,b_{i}>0$

Comment: Just edited it before your comment.

Comment: This question was from China a senior Olympics(IMO student in china) coach,and

Answer (score -5):

Hint: because all numbers are positive, the expression is equivalent to:

$(1-\|\vec{a}\|_{3}^{3})^{1/3}
\cdot (1-\|\vec{b}\|_{3}^{3})^{1/3}
\geq 1-\langle \vec{c}+\vec{r};\vec{c}-\vec{r}\rangle
- 2\|\vec{r}\|_{1}$

where $c_{i}=\frac{a_{i}+b_{i}}{2}$ and $r_{i}=\frac{a_{i}-b_{i}}{2}$.

Hint 2:

$1-\sum_{i}a_{i}^{3}\geq \sum_{i}a_{i}^{2}-\sum_{i}a_{i}^{3}=\sum_{i}a_{i}(1-a_{i})$

Comment: If you care about your reputation: simply deleting this answer will give you (+10).