# Proof or disproof $Y = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i} + \sum_{i \not=j}^{n} a^{2}_{i}b^{2}_{j} - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i} \ge 0$

Tags: inequality

In my attempt to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/812273/how-prove-1-sum-i-1na3-i1-3-cdot-1-sum-i-1nb3-i1-3/840063#840063)

I came cross this question :

if $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}a^2_{i}\le 1,\sum_{i=1}^{n}b^2_{i}\le 1 $$ do we have ?

$$Y = 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a^{2}_{i} b^{2}_{i} + \sum_{i \not=j}^{n} a^{2}_{i}b^{2}_{j} - 2\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i} b_{i} \ge 0$$

Comment: This obviously fails for $n=1$.

Comment: and for $n > 1$ ?

Comment: Hello, Note $a_{i}>0,b_{i}>0$

Comment: No, this inequelity is false .., your inequality is a rock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a=(0.5 , 0) and b=(1 , 0) to show the inequality is wrong for n=2.

Conclude by recurring (adding 0 to each vector last coordinate).